# Azure DevOps Pipeline Azure SQL Deploy won't work with SQL script (Failed to login)

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

I've been trying to deploy a database via a pipeline from Azure DevOps to an Azure resource group.

I have an ARM template for my database server in my Repo along with my DACPAC file.
In my release pipeline I first deploy the database server with an admin user defined in the ARM template to my resource group.
Then I use the "Azure SQL DacpacTask" to deploy the database schema. Here I give the admin credentials and it works flawlessly.

[image: ARM template for database server]

The issue is that the customer doesn't want it deployed as a DACPAC but rather an SQL script. They've given me a "CREATE TO..."-script from their database, created inside MS SQL Studio, which is also in my Repo.

The "Azure SQL DacpacTask" inside my release pipeline has an option for using an SQL file instead of DACPAC, but it doesn't work for me.

[image: Azure SQL DacpacTask]

But no matter how I do it, my pipeline fails when running the "Azure SQL DacpacTask" and all I get, even in debug-mode is "Login failed for user '***'".

[image: error message]

I can connect to the SQL Server through MSSQL Studio on my local machine using the admin credentials defined in my ARM template.

I've tried by adding the agent's IP before running the SQL script, but with no success.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong? Why is it that it keeps failing to log in?

They want it deployed with little to no human interaction. Is it doable only through the ADO pipeline?

EDIT
Additional info:

- I have tried with hardcoded password and user with no luck.
- If I manually create a database and then try to deploy one via script and pipeline, it fails because a database already exists, and not because of a failed login.
- I've setup Audit in Azure which generates 2 files with little to no info. I'm not sure what I'm looking at.

Comment: Firstly, DACPAC is the right way to go but there is no arguing with customers. To run the script you might need to use a Powershell task and `Invoke-SQLCmd` or you could use `CmdLine@2` and call `SQLCMD.EXE`

Comment: I agree, but it is how it is. The "Azure SQL DacpacTask" action, when set to deploy via SQL script, actually invokes "Invoke-SQLCmd" behind the scenes. I have tried a Powershell task and trying the same, but with same result getting a "Login failed for user"-error, unfortunately.

Comment: I also tried to use dacpac task to run a script but couldn’t get it working. I forget why.

Comment: Login failed is pretty straightforward. It’s not a network issue. You could check sql server logs to find more details - wrong password / disabled account / incorrect default db.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've heard that, but I can't seem to find the server logs anywhere. Rightclicking on the server in Object Explorer i SSMS18 doesn't give me the "SQL Server Logs" option.

Comment: Can you see this view? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current

Comment: Yes I do, and it looks like it connects to the server, but then it's blocked by a firewall rule, which I don't understand, since I setup a firewall rule for the IP of the agent before trying to deploy. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but can't see what.

Comment: I just created a firewall rule allowing every IP access with same error message and the sys.event_log shows the same.

Comment: Can you show a matching tie from the table in your question. Firewall won’t cause login failed.

Comment: Sorry not entirely understood. Matching tie?

Comment: Matching record from sys.event_log

Comment: I think this is to do with the password, either special character being stripped off or an extra space etc.  Can you for testing hardcode the password and username in the arm template and give it a test run to see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with hardcoded password and the password contains only numbers, lower case and upper case letters, so no special characters.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No can't see anything that should match.

Comment: So you are unable to find a match? BEcause this table will give you more information about the specific failure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current#EventTypes Are there any more sepcific details in your error message?

Comment: You may need to turn on auditing as per here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6732/azure-sql-database-auditing/ the objective being to get more details about the actual login failure. Alternatively see if you can get more detail out of devops, although I know that the dacpac task hides a lot of details.

Comment: I can see three rows with action_name "DATABASE AUTHENTICATION FAILED" after one row that say "DATABASE AUTHENTICATION SUCCEEDED".
The failed rows contain errorcode 18456